# What exception must be made if $|a|=|b|=1$ to $|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The problem is :

> Prove that $$|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|=1$$ if either $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$. What exception must be made if $|a|=|b|=1$.(where $a$, $b$ are both complex number and $|1-\bar{a}b|\neq 1$)

I can proof $$|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}|=1$$ if either $|a|=1$ or $|b|=1$. But I do not understand the request **What exception must be made if $|a|=|b|=1$**.

Comment: I feel something is missing in the question prove what? I guess a,b are complex numbers? Explain more

Comment: Yes, you are right. I add it.@AmerYR

Comment: Could the denominator be zero?

Comment: Thank you! Following your direction I found if $|a|=|b|=1$ then $Im(a\bar{b})\neq0$@AnginaSeng

Comment: Your condition (if $|a| = |b| =1$, then $\text{Im}(a\bar b) \ne 0$) is sufficient for the equation to hold, but it is not necessary. For example. the equation holds when $a = -1, b = 1$, or vice versa. There is a *simpler* condition that exactly encapsulates the cases where the equation fails. Note that if $|a| = 1$, then $\bar a = 1/a$.